# Optimized way to find every path from root to leaf in a non - binary tree

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, runtime

I have a 2D array which stores list of backpointers to some locations in the same array. I need to traverse from the last entry in the 2d array to the entry which doesn't have any backpointer stored. Technically it is like traversing through non-binary tree.

My current naive implementation is

```
def traverse_tree (root,cur_path,backpointer_array,pathlist):
    print "adding root " + str(root)
    cur_path.append(root)
    children = backpointer_array[root[0]][root[1]]
    if(len(children)==0):
        pathlist.append(cur_path)
    else:
        for child in children:          
            traverse_tree(child,cur_path[:],backpointer_array,pathlist)
```

The code works fine when size of matrix is small [5 * 5] , but when I try to run it with larger matrix [50 * 500] , the code takes forever to execute . Is there a way to optimize this implementation

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic programming to store in memory "sub-paths" which can be reused

You are going to need a map `M` that maps each node of your array to the list of paths from that node.

If your data structure is a tree, you don't gain anything, but in the general case, you can go from exponential time to linear

Pseudocode

```
M = map<Node, List<Path>> // Path is just a list of Nodes
List<Path> traverse_tree (CurrentNode)
    if(M contains CurrentNode)
        return M[CurrentNode]
    answer = List<Path>
    for each children C of CurrentNode
        subpath = traverse_tree(C)
        // Shorthand to say prepend CurrentNode to all paths in subpath
        answer.append(CurrentNode+subpath) 
    M[CurrentNode] = answer // Dynamic programming time!
    return answer

Full_Path_List_From_Root = traverse_tree(Root)
```

Notes :

- If there is a cycle, this can loop infinitely (but note that you cannot get all paths in finite time anyways)
- Each node is explored only once
- Here is an interesting example

[image: Example where naive implementation is exponential]

Imagine there are N stack of 2 nodes (in the picture there are only 3). In total, there are 2^N paths. The naive implementation visits the leaves an exponential number of time. If you store the subpaths, you visit each node only once instead of an exponential number of time (however, there are no miracles, if there is an exponential number of paths, your list of paths will be exponential)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a much better performance if you will use multi-threading and Queue.

here is an example of usage, you should rewrite it and implement it in your scenario, if you need help to do that I will be more than happy to assist.

here is a simple demo:

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

# Set up some global variables
worker_threads = 64
my_queue = Queue()

# the data we work on
my_data = range(1000)

def Worker(i, q,):
    # This is the worker thread function. 
    # It processes items in the queue one after another.  
    # These daemon threads go into an infinite loop, 
    # and only exit when the main thread ends.
    while True:
        data = q.get()

        print "[*] ", data, " i am", i

        q.task_done()


# Set up some threads to fetch the enclosures
for i in range(worker_threads):
    worker = Thread(target=Worker, args=(i, my_queue,))
    worker.setDaemon(True)
    worker.start()

# Put the enclosure data into the queue.
for data in my_data:
    my_queue.put(data)

# Now wait for the queue to be empty, indicating that we have processed all of the data.
print '*** Main thread waiting'
my_queue.join()
print '*** Done'
```